# urllib2 timeout is incorrect for certain sites

Tags: python, http, timeout, urllib2

It appears that the `timeout` parameter in `urllib2.urlopen` does not work consistently. Why is this?

I tested the parameter on some sample urls below, measuring the total time the call took before timing out. Some pages were accurate, others were not. Is this a bug with `urllib2`? Can anyone explain why this is?

Below is some sample code I used to test the timeout functionality:

```
import datetime, urllib2, logging, pprint
timeout_sites = [
  "http://10.255.255.1", # Unreachable
  "http://example.com:81", # No DNS name
  "http://google.com:81", # Closed port
  "http://httpbin.org/delay/10" # Waits 10 secs, then responds
]
# Calculate the timeout times and put them in here.
timeouts = {}
for url in timeout_sites:
  timeouts[url] = []
  for t in range(0, 5, 1):
    # Save the start time.
    start = datetime.datetime.utcnow()
    try:
      urllib2.urlopen(url, timeout = t)
    except Exception as e:
      # We're expecting a timeout exception. Measure the total time.
      ttime = (datetime.datetime.utcnow() - start).total_seconds()
      timeouts[url].append((t, ttime))
      logging.info("%s: Timeout=%s, Actual=%s (e=%s %s)"%(url, t, ttime, type(e), e))
    else:
      raise Exception("Expecting itmeout")
pprint.pprint(timeouts)
```

I would expect the measured timeout time to be relatively close to the specified time, but it appears that in some cases it is off by a factor of two:

```
{'http://10.255.255.1': [(0, 0.001),
                         (1, 1.0),
                         (2, 2.002),
                         (3, 3.001),
                         (4, 4.001)],
 'http://example.com:81': [(0, 0.003),
                           (1, 2.002),
                           (2, 4.003),
                           (3, 6.003),
                           (4, 8.003)],
 'http://google.com:81': [(0, 0.033),
                          (1, 2.002),
                          (2, 4.003),
                          (3, 6.002),
                          (4, 8.002)],
 'http://httpbin.org/delay/10': [(0, 0.132),
                                 (1, 1.029),
                                 (2, 2.033),
                                 (3, 3.031),
                                 (4, 4.037)]}
```

Comment: Was going to say I couldn't reproduce this, but then got: `'http://httpbin.org/delay/10': [(0, 0.016), (1, 1.114), (2, 6.591), (3, 6.569), (4, 4.11)]}`, which a tad more eccentric...

Comment: Hmm, I'm running Python 2.7 on Windows, this may very well be platform specific.

Comment: I am running the same. However, my first comment has really confused me. I couldn't replicate your issue over several attempts so was going to write-off as a "cannot reproduce". Did you look at the order of my output though? The middle two runs took longer than the last.

Comment: Yes, I see. I'm guessing that `urllib2` uses the same timeout for various parts of the urlopen process (DNS, open connection, etc). It's possible it automatically retries these parts, which may explain why the actual times seem to be integer multiples of specified timeout.

Comment: `requests` iirc from something unrelated that I read last week does not run  repeats by default. Is there a reason you need `urllib2`?

Comment: I know all about `requests`, I'm stuck with `urllib2` for now.

Comment: Log the exceptions as well; they might offer some additional info:
 - configure logging:

`logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO,
    format='[%(asctime)s] - %(levelname)s - %(message)s', datefmt='%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')`

 - catch the exception:

`except Exception as e:`

 - log it:

`logging.info("%s: Timeout=%s, Actual=%s, :%s"%(url, t, ttime, e))`

I should point out I get consistent results on my ArchLinux notebook: 
`[(0, 0.003643), (1, 1.139166), (2, 2.139759), (3, 3.139544), (4, 4.151354)]}`

Comment: Ah fair enough :( I only posted because I found something completely different than just being off by a factor of 2. Yet it also feels strange that it would be a fluke so specific to go in multiples of 2 in some cases too. I honestly don't know what's going on.

Comment: @IonutTicus Done, intrestingly, the first three urls raise a `urllib2.URLError` and the last one raises `socket.timeout`